# How to add a line break AFTER a JavaScript variable?

Tags: jquery, underscore.js, each

I'm looping through a popup window, retrieving the textbox values inside said popup window, and copying those values into another textbox in another popup window. Here's my code

```
var textAreas = this.$contents.find('textarea')
    textBoxValue = '';
var copyPopupTextBox = $('.copy-popup-text-box');

_.each(textAreas, function(area, i){
    var value = $(area).val();
    textBoxValue += value;
    copyPopuptextBox += textBoxValue;
}
```

If that looks a bit confusing out of the context of my project, the only thing you need to worry about is the value variable at the beginning of the each loop. I want a line break to be inserted after `$(area).val()` has found the value within a textarea the loop has iterated through.

I've tried putting `p` tags on either side of var value's content, `br` tags, `/n` strings, as well as some RegExp stuff I don't quite understand...

I have a feeling this is something un-extraordinary and straightforward but I just can't see it at the moment O_O

Thx
- Gaweyne

Comment: Have you tried `\n` rather than `/n`?

Comment: Yes, I meant backslash n, but there's something wrong with this keyboard.

How would I insert \n correctly here?

$area.val() + "\n" ?

Comment: Ah. That was the right way. There was just a missing semi colon much earlier in my code. Fail.